# JQuery .on() change event not firing(page is inside a .load())

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Okay, so I've been looking for an answer for this for a couple of hours now and found nothing that works.

I have a page that I load inside a div after a .click event, so that looks like this:

```
$('#mybutton').click( function () { $('#mydiv').load('myinnerpage.aspx'); });
```

Then I have inside myinnerpage.js I have:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=rbfileByNameOrID]:radio', function () {
if ($('input#rbByFileName').attr('checked'))
    fileSelectionBy('filename');
else
    fileSelectionBy('fileid'); 
});
```

the change function never gets fired, unless I open myinnerpage.aspx by itself.

Comment: Does `$('#mybutton')` contain your button when you're registering the click handler or is it loaded to the page afterwards? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Is the innerpage.js written to the client?

Comment: could you please show how the JS is embedded inside the inner page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: innerpage.js is included in a script tag in the innerpage.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put your myinnerpage.js code in your main javascript, instead of in your included page ?

If you can't, i've not the "good-solution", but this can help you : jQueryMobile-Navigation had the same problem when they loaded page with ajax, and they used a non-jquery solution to solve that. In their $.ajax->success, they use innerHTML :

```
[...]

//workaround to allow scripts to execute when included in page divs
all.get( 0 ).innerHTML = html;

[...]
```

You can see their full code [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.navigation.js).

It works with script-tag **AND inline-javascript** included in page divs.

Comment: I added the myinnerpage.js code into the home.html page and this fixed the problem. I would prefer a way where I didn't have to do that but this works for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try firing the event manually?

```
$('#mybutton').click( function () { 
  $('#mydiv').load('myinnerpage.aspx', function(){
      $('input[name=rbfileByNameOrID]:radio').trigger('change')
   }); 
});
```

Comment: The event may be "bound" to `document`, but it's "delegated" to the input.  This won't work.  It should be `$('input[name=rbfileByNameOrID]:radio').trigger('change');`  Also, I think he wants the `change` event to be bound to the element, so it triggers when it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#rbByFileName').trigger('change');
```

OR:

```
$('input#rbByFileName').change();

$('#mybutton').click( function () { 
  $('#mydiv').load('myinnerpage.aspx', function(){
      $('input#rbByFileName').change();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I think he wants the `change` event to trigger when it's supposed to.  I think the issue here is the event isn't getting bound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when `.load` is ran, the contents of `myinnerpage.aspx` is placed (in its entirety) into `#mydiv`.  Any `<script>` tags will run, but they'll be from the path of the current page, so you may need to check your file paths.

You may need to change your scripts to use absolute paths instead of relative paths, because `../` may not be the same on the current page and the loaded page.